# Black areas when using RDP and Hyper-V VM console

Tags: display, remote-desktop, hyper-v, virtual-console

OK,
So when I use RDC (Remote Desktop Connection) to connect to a remote machine, the screen is full of random black areas. The way I managed to resolve this was by unchecking `Persistent bitmap caching`, as illustrated here:

[image: Remote Desktop Connection]

This same issue occurs when I open a Hyper-V VM console, and to manage that it is necessary not to use `Enhanced session mode`. This is set up in the `Hyper-V Settings > Enhanced Session Mode Policy` and `Hyper-V Settings > Enhanced Session Mode`.

This is what the screen looks like with enhanced session mode:

[image: Enhanced session mode on]

And this is the same screen with enhanced session mode turned off:

[image: Enhanced session mode off]

While these solutions do solve my immediate issue, which is not to have those pesky black rectangles, I wonder what could be the cause of this, and, more importantly, is there a way to resolve this issue without turning off enhanced session mode in Hyper-V, as I am really benefiting from the functionality it brings?

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone cares, my display drivers are up to date. I have Intel HD Graphics 4000 and Nvidia NVS 5200M, and the laptop is set to boot NVS 5200M.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like cache corruption on the client side. Can you please stop all MSTSC connections, then remove the following folder:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`

That should clear the local cache and you should be free of black squares.

Comment: This has been bugging me for months.  Many thanks!